# I have call this function multiple times to sort the elements in my record structure properly

Tags: c, loops, sorting

I'm learning C and I am writing a basic program to store records. When I try to sort the elements in my array of structures (I don't know if I said that properly) alphabetically by last name, I find that I have to call the function multiple times to get it to actually sort all of the elements.

I believe that the problem is with ret = strcmp(rec[j2].lastname, rec[j2 + 1].lastname); and where it is in the code. It runs once and sorts two elements in the array, but I have to call the function multiple times to get it to sort fully. I have tried placing that line in its own for() loop and while() loop but I have not found a solution yet.

```
 typedef struct rec {
    int recordnumber;
    char firstname[20];
    char lastname[20];
    int age;
    char gender;
} record; 

void SortArr(record* rec, int numrecsread) 
{ 
    int sortchoice;
    int i2, j2, temp, ret;
    record *r1, *r2;
    record trec;

    printf("Press 1 to sort by record number or press 2 to sort by last name.\n");
    scanf("%d", &sortchoice);


    if (sortchoice == 1)
    {
        printf("You have chosen to sort record numbers in ascending order...\n");
        for (i2 = 1; i2 < numrecsread; i2++)
        {
            for (j2 = 0; j2 < numrecsread - 1; j2++)
            {
                if (rec[j2].recordnumber > rec[i2].recordnumber)
                {
                    Swap(&rec[i2], &rec[j2]);

                }
            }
        }
    }
    else if (sortchoice == 2) 
    { 
        printf("You have chosen to sort last names alphabetically...\n");

        for (i2 = 1; i2 < numrecsread; i2++)
        {
            for (j2 = 0; j2 < numrecsread - 1; j2++)
            {
                ret = strcmp(rec[j2].lastname, rec[j2 + 1].lastname); //this has to be called multiple times to fully sort
                if (ret > 0)
                {

                    Swap(&rec[i2], &rec[j2]);

                }
            }
        }

    }
    else if (sortchoice < 1 || sortchoice > 2)
    {
        printf("Invalid input.\n");
    }

}
```

Right now I have four records stored in my array back in main. The expected result is that they are sorted alphabetically by last name in just one call to the function. Sorting numerically by record number works fine.

Comment: You are comparing different elements in each of the sort loops. It's no wonder that they don't behave the same way.

Comment: Use `qsort` and a comparison function. This is what it was made for.

Comment: See http://c-faq.com/lib/qsort2.html.

Answer (score 0):

here is an algorithm, in c, for performing a 'bubble' sort.

Notice the drastic differences between the posted code and the bubble sort algorithm.

Note: there are lots of other algorithms for sorting, but the OPs posted code is not one of them.

```
// A function to implement bubble sort 
void bubbleSort(int arr[], int n) 
{ 
   int i, j; 
   for (i = 0; i < n-1; i++)       

       // Last i elements are already in place    
       for (j = 0; j < n-i-1; j++)  
           if (arr[j] > arr[j+1]) 
              swap(&arr[j], &arr[j+1]); 
}
```

the above algorithm is from: [bubble sort](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/bubble-sort/)